# Node-edit a group of paths (inkscape)

Tags: inkscape

The documentation of Inkscape [states](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html) (for groups)

> you can only node-edit one path at a time

However, this is extremely annoying when working for instance on vectorized bitmaps which consists of several layers.
In addition, I found [this](https://inkscape.org/en/~doctormo/%E2%98%85multipath) mentioning multipath edition being supported since 0.48...

So can multipath node-edit be performed "out-of-the-box"? Or would there be a workaround to apply e.g. the same translation to several close nodes in the group? Or at least a way to select several nodes in a group?

**[EDIT]**
Following the answers from Scribblemacher and the comment from Moini, I can sum up the situation for inkscape 0.92 as:

- the documentation is outdated, multiple paths edit is indeed possible
- <kbd>F1</kbd> and multiple select, then <kbd>F2</kbd> works for *simple **ungrouped** paths*
- for some (unknown) reason, the previous answer does not work on vectorized objects and manual selection of the path using node edit (<kbd>F2</kbd>), then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click is necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit modes from multiple paths at once (tested with Inkscape 0.92).

1. Using the select tool <kbd>F1</kbd>, select the objects with the nodes you want to edit.
2. Change to the node tool <kbd>F2</kbd>

You can select objects across layers as well.

Comment: Yes, you certainly can do it in 0.92 - [animated screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/m2jxtSW)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. It seems to be a little more difficult with the vectorized objects (no idea why). Just F1, select F2 did not work, I had to 1) ungroup all paths 2) set node tool with F2 3) select the paths as well as I could with Shift+click...

Comment: I'd just select the objects with the node tool, instead of selecting them before switching. This allows you to directly select the path that is highlighted, regardless of any grouping (Ctrl + Click with selection tool does the same). Hold Shift and click on them with the node tool. Then select the nodes.